# How to implement (UI-wise) a button

Tags: user-interface, layout, user-controls

I am designing the (G)UI of a program, and have stumbled across a problem; The program will convert a number into different units, and the layout of a unit been converted to is:

[Unit name (when clicked gives information)]
[Special status, if any]
[Output in textfield that can also be used for input (to convert to other units)]

I want the user to be able to copy an outputnumber onto the clipboard, without having to mess around with highlighting and finding the right buttons to press. So, I thought I'd make a button after the text-output field, saying something like "C" or "Copy".

But I was reading on [joelonsoftware.com](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000063.html) yesterday, and discovered that users seem to be cursorclumsy. So what should I do?

I've thought about a number of different options:

1. Click on textfield to copy to clipboard - BUT: I want to use it for input as well
2. Pressing a numeral on the keyboard to copy the respective one - BUT: There will probably be more than 10, and I need them for new input
3. Bigger Copy button, like on that actually says "Copy" - Hmm, would this work? I know that I like to use the keyboard when I can, so a solution involving it would be nice.
4. Each unit will have its own space, where everything (name, textfield etc.) fits in. What if it would copy to clipboard when clicked anywhere in that space except for on the name or textfield. - BUT: What if you miss, meaning to click below one textfield, and clicking above another?
5. But what about highlighting the unit's space as I went along? - Could still mean trouble...

What do you think? I think I just might opt for #3 - Bigger copy-button..

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with a Copy button after every field if you feel that it's going to be a very common operation.

Two suggestions, however:

1. In terms of look and feel, make sure that the button is clearly associated with the field. For a text field, the best way to do this is to put the Copy button inside the text field (on the right side - but be prepared to handle RTL languages by switching its position as needed!).
2. To avoid making it overly big, don't use any text, but rather use the stock Windows icon for Copy (like this one: [image]), and put the text into its tooltip. If you do that, you may also get rid of button border entirely, further reducing its size, though you'd still want some visual hover indicator to make it clear that it's an active UI element. In fact, you might want to specifically copy Vista/Win7 Explorer (also seen in IE7/8) UI for location field and the Reload icon in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally click on the wrong area, you could just click on the right area after that.  If your issue lies in the user not knowing when they click on the wrong area, just highlight the last-clicked area.

Is there a problem with copying whatever is in the textfield when they click on it?  So what if it's being used for input?  They're just going to copy the value they need *after* they type values in.

You could also have a `ctrl-click` or `shift-click` in the text box be a copy.

Most people know how to copy text on their own computer.  Perhaps the best solution is to just auto-highlight all the text in a textbox when it gets focus so they can just ctrl-c to copy or start typing to begin input.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution #3 is the best in your list, but I would like to see a sketch of your GUI.

Answer (score 0):

For sheer speed, the keyboard is the way to go. How about letters A-Z to copy the text boxes instead? Skip “E” to allow scientific notation to be inputted. Potential speed is high, but learnability is low. I’d expect users will have a hard time figuring out this UI even with explanatory text on the page/window, and if users have to read explanatory text, then the time that takes will likely negate the time savings of the UI, unless the user is using the app all the time (Joel also writes correctly that users hate to read).

For an app that will be used only occasionally, the big button is a better choice, the bigger the better, as predicted by Fitts’s Law. And absolutely label it “Copy,” not “C” and not an icon, to maximize learnability. Your other ideas have learnability and tolerance issues without the speed of the keyboard.

That said, I think you’re taking what Joel says too far. Certainly you want to eliminate unnecessary clicks, but the typical design for this type of app would require one click on the text box (which should by default highlight the whole value) followed by one click on a Copy menu item –or better, Alt-C or Ctrl-C from the keyboard. It’s hard for me to imagine a task where saving one click or a couple keyboard presses would be worth the clutter of a bank of Copy buttons beside your text boxes. Are you also going to have buttons for Paste and Clear? At some point the clutter will slow your users down more than the extra click.

How often are users going to be copying? If it’s really dozens of times per session, then you should re-think the whole design approach because *any* copying and pasting of one number at a time is going to get tedious. Maybe you should support batch processing, taking multiple numbers at once and outputting results in a form already suitable for the expected use. Maybe have it work within other apps like the way Enso does: user highlights a number in any document or text field of any app, commands Convert - Feet - Meters and it’s changed in the document or field.

Comment: Good point, which I also thought about, the thing is; I already thought about this, and a large portion of the input is going to be letters (should have put that in the question). Think I'll go with the big button instead.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you do, it is important to use the OS standard keyboard and mouse event bindings and preferable look-and-feel too otherwise users get confused.